# All power series has a point that is not regular.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Definition: Let $f = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n $ a power series and $0<R< \infty$ its convergence ratio. We say that $z_0 \in \mathbb C, |z_0| = R$ is a regular point if $\exists r > 0$ such that $f$ has an analytic extension in $B(z_0, r)$.

Question: Let $f = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n $ a power series and $0<R< \infty$ its convergence ratio. So exists $w_0$ that is not a regular point of $f$.

My attempt: Let's denote by $frB(0,R)$ = {$ z \in \mathbb C: |z| = R  $}. Let's supose that all $w \in \mathbb C, |w| = R$ is regular point. So, for all w, |w| = R, exists an analytic extension of $f$ in $B(w, r_w)$. So, {$ B(w, r_w) : w \in frB(0,R) $} is a open cover for $fr B(0,R)$. So exists $w_1,...,w_n \in fr B(0,R)$ that $\left \{ B(w_i, r_{w_i}): i = 1,...,n  \right \}$ covers $fr B(0,R)$. Let's define $\epsilon = \min{  r_{w_i}  } $ Let's take $g_i$, the analytic extension of $f$ associate to $w_i$. If I could define

$$ F(z) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
f(z), \quad z \in B(0,R)
\\ 
g_i(z), \quad z \in B(w_i, \varepsilon )
\end{matrix}\right. $$

With this, how can I get a contradiction?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the $B(w_i,r_{w_i})$'s cover $frB(0,R)$, the $B(w_i,r_{w_i})$'s and $B(0,R)$ cover the clausure of $B(0,R)$. This is a open covering so it also covers $B(0,R+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Now you have by definition that the radius of convergence of $F$ is $S>R$. This leads to a contradiction with the Cauchy-Hadamard formula because the power series of $F$ must be the same that the power series of $f$.

Comment: How proof that the power series of $F$ is the same of $f$?

Comment: @vinicius The restriction to $B(0,R)$ of $F$ coincides with the function $f$. Now it is a basic complex analysis result that two holomorphic functions defined on a disk $B(z_0,R)$ are the same if and only if the coefficients of their power series (around $z_0$) coincide.

Comment: @vinucius If you haven't seen it, you can inmediate obtain it as consequence of Cauchy's formula for the disk.

Comment: @Jonh can you tell me why you know there is a $\epsilon$ such that it also covers $B(0,R+\varepsilon)$

Comment: @noname1014Aug It is a theorem that for a compact set $C$  and a disjoint closed set $F$ in a metric space $dist(C,F)=\inf_{x\in C,y\in F}d(x,y)>\epsilon$ for some positive $\epsilon>0$. See exercise 1.21 in http://www.ime.unicamp.br/~marcio/ps2009/spivak for a reference.

Comment: @noname1014 (I misread the alias)

Comment: @Jonh thank you, but how to use this theorem to know it also covers $B(0,R+\varepsilon$?

Comment: @noname1014 You know that  $U:=\left(\cup_iB(w_i,r_{w_i})\right)\cup B(0,R)$ cover the closure of $B(0,R)$ (cause $U$ is open and cover $B(0,R)$). Now consider the closed $U^c$ and the compact $\overline{D(0,R)}$ and apply the above theorem.